# Is this function safe for concurrent execution?

Tags: scala, concurrency

```
  def isSafe( i:Int) = {
    var count = i
    var acc = 0
    while(count!=0){
      acc += i*i
      count -= 1
    }
    acc
  }
```

Comment: You mean `count` not `cont` in the loop?

Comment: Apart from the typo, I don't see why not but I'm not a Scala guy.

Comment: I'd rewrited method, sorry for my carelessness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by safe you mean that it returns the same result independently of how many threads invoke it and in which order, then yes, it's safe. This is because it doesn't modify any shared memory locations, only its local variables.

Answer (score 3):

It's safe, there's no shared state that could lead to cross-thread contamination.

It's also massively over-complicated, the following definition is both shorter and faster:

```
def isSafe(i: Int) = i * i * i
```

Comment: function in op-post is just simplificated version (concept) of real function